# How to load data into service without resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I want to fetch some data from a server and copy it to a service before a routechange is completed:

```
when(
  '/detail/:id', 
  {
    templateUrl: './partials/views/detail.php',
    controller: 'detailCtrl',
    resolve: {
      init: function($route,$q,shipmentn){
        var deffered = $q.defer();

        shipmentn.getSingle($route.current.params.id).then(function(promise){
          shipmentn.data = promise.data;
          deffered.resolve(promise);
        });

        return deffered.promise;
      }
    }
  }
)
```

As you can see, i am doing this inside the `then()` function to make sure that the request has been completed.

What bothers me, is that i have to inject another dependency (`init`) into my controller and have to return a promise which is never used.

How could i avoid this?

Comment: What is the use of this? To cache a value in the service?

Comment: @Fourth
i am using this to fetch data which will be displayed in the view. The basic idea is to provide the complete data to be shown through a service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trick might be to pass the service you want in your controller to the resolve function of the defered object, after the service itself finished its loading:

```
when('/detail/:id', {
  templateUrl: './partials/views/detail.php',   
  controller: function($scope,service){}, //<-- Controller with the service dependency
  resolve: {
    service: function($route,$q,shipmentn){
      var deffered = $q.defer();       
      shipmentn.getSingle($route.current.params.id).then(function(promise){
        shipmentn.data = promise.data;
        deffered.resolve(shipmentn); //<-- the deffered resolves the service
      });
      return deffered.promise;
    }
}})
```

regards

Comment: As this exactly achieves what i wanted, i'll accept this one.
Thank you :)

Comment: After thinking about this for a while, i wonder why the hell it's working. What is happening internally and what is resolve()doing when called without any arguments?

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking to send data to the controller, you don't need to store it in the service, it can just be resolved to the controller:

router:

```
when('/detail/:id', {templateUrl: './partials/views/detail.php',   controller: 'detailCtrl',resolve: {

            shipment: function($route,$q,shipmentn){
                return shipmentn.getSingle($route.current.params.id));
            }

        }})
```

service:

```
getSingle: function(id){
 var deferred = q.defer();

 $http.get(...).then(function(response){
  deferred.resolve(response.data);
 }

 return deferred.promise;
}
```

controller:

```
module.controller('detailController', ['shipment', function(shipment){
 ...
}]);
```

On the controller, shipment will be whatever is returned from response.data in the http.get.

Comment: I am aware of this. However, as the data has to be accessible global, i prefer storing it in a service